# How to build human-like search-engine queries?

Tags: search, web-scraping, bots, google-search, search-engine-bots

I am interacting with a search engine programmatically and I need to trick it into thinking that I am a human making queries, as opposed to a robot. This involves generating queries for which it seems plausible that any ordinary user would search for, like "ncaa football schedule" or "When was the lunar landing?" I'll be making over a thousand of these queries daily, and searching for random words out of a dictionary won't cut it, since that's not a very typical search habit.

So far I have thought of a few ways to generate realistic queries:

- Obtain a list of the top google (or Yahoo or Bing, etc) searches for the day
- Make use of Google's autocomplete feature by entering a random word from the dictionary followed by a space and scraping the recommended queries.

The latter approach sounds like it would involve a lot of reverse engineering. And with the former approach, I've been unable to find a list of more than 80-or-so queries - the only sources I've found are [AOL trends](http://search.aol.com/aol/trends) (50-100) and [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/widget?pn=p1&tn=30&h=413) (30).

How might I go about generating a large set of human-like search phrases?
(For any language-dependent answers: I'm programming in Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this most likely breaks Google's TOS, you can scrape the autocomplete data easily:

```
import requests
import json

def autocomplete(query, depth=1, lang='en'):
    if depth == 0:
        return

    response = requests.get('https://clients1.google.com/complete/search', params={
        'client': 'hp',
        'hl': lang,
        'q': query
    }).text

    data = response[response.index('(') + 1:-1]
    o = json.loads(data)

    for result in o[1]:
        suggestion = result[0].replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', '')
        yield suggestion

        if depth > 1:
            for s in autocomplete(suggestion, depth - 1, lang):
                yield s
```

`autocomplete('a', depth=2)` gives you the top 110 queries that start with `a` (with some duplicates). Scrape each letter to a depth of 2, and you should have a ton of legitimate queries to choose from.

Comment: Wow, much easier than expected. Thanks for this. It generates duplicates for depth > 1, though this can easily be fixed by changing `yield suggestion` to `if depth == 1: yield suggestion`